# Simple random sampling

Tags: probability

In probability, why when you do random sampling without replacement:

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=-\frac{\sigma^2}{N-1}.$$

$N$ is the total population, $\sigma$ is the variance of population.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because the random variables $X_i$ are identically distributed, the random variables $(X_i,X_j)$ are identically distributed and the sum of the $N$ random variables is deterministic.

Thus, considering $c=\mathrm{cov}(X_i,X_j)$ and $\sigma^2=\mathrm{var}(X_i)$, one gets
$$
0=\mathrm{var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^N\mathrm{var}(X_i)+\sum_{i\ne j}\mathrm{cov}(X_i,X_j)=N\sigma^2+N(N-1)c.
$$

Comment: Excuse me. I don't know the properties of random sampling. I wonder now why the summation is deterministic.

Comment: I guess because it's sampling without replacement. So after you get all the samples out, it should be deterministic.

Comment: The probability that the sum is equal to a particular number is $1$; hence it's deterministic.  If you do the sampling again, you'll get a different set of values of $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots,X_N$, but their sum will still be the same.